# Using Rails find_or_initialize_by_email, how to determine if record if found or initialized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my controllers, I'm doing:

```
user = User.find_or_initialize_by_email(@omniauth['info']['email'])
```

I then need to know if the records was found or initialized. I had tried this:

```
if user
else
end
```

But that does not work as there will always be a user. What is the right way to know if find or initialize found or initialized?

Comment: Be aware that the dynamic matchers are deprecated. You should use this instead: `User.find_or_initialize_by(email: @omniauth['info']['email'])`

Comment: Care that `find_or_initialize` is going to be deprecated, try `first_or_initialize` instead: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use `persisted?`:

```
if user.persisted?
```

[edgeguides.rubyonrails.org](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org) says the following about `find_or_initialize_by`:

> The find_or_initialize_by method will work just like find_or_create_by
>   but it will call new instead of create. This means that a new model
>   instance will be created in memory but won't be saved to the database.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to @pdoherty926's answer is to use the `new_record?` method.

```
if user.new_record?
```

It would return the opposite truthy value from `persisted?` though, so you have a choice on which works for your conditional logic. (I tend to find `if` to be more readable than `unless` sometimes, for example.)